# How can I separate the first word of a string?

Tags: python, string

I made a script with BeautifulSoup4 that retrieves the price of a crypto-currency from coinmarketcap.

The text I get is in a string:

```
result = $3.75
```

how can I convert the result to float? I have to delete the $, how to do with a split?

```
result_without_dollar = result.split("$")
```

I tried but I only get back """.

I'd like to get

```
price = 3.75 , and price.type is float
```

Comment: Do you mean `result = '$3.75'`?

Comment: There are APIs that return cryptocurrency prices, why are you scraping a web page?

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `split()` you can do this like this:

```py
result_without_dollar = float(result.split('$')[1])
```

Notice that `split()` returns a `list`.

However, you can achieve this more simply like this:

```py
result_without_dollar = float(result[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it !

Comment: But I don't understand the second point ?

Comment: Basically instead of splitting the string on the dollar sign we can just use `slices` and slice the string in such a way that we only get the number and then we convert it to a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also be a bit more specific about the value of result, and check the format of the string first, matching `$` and capturing the numerical value in group 1.

```
\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `\$` Match `$`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` Match an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

If the pattern matches, print group 1.

```
import re

result = "$3.75"
m = re.match(r"\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$", result)
if m:
    fl = float(m.group(1))
    print(fl)
```

Output

```
3.75
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```py
result_without_dollar=result.replace('$','')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the string in question is `'result = $3.75'`, not clear from the question.

Find the position of the `$` symbol and then slice the string.

```
s = 'result = $3.75'
price = float(s[s.find('$')+1:])
```

Output

```
3.75
```